# Error using Foundation’s Sticky and Toggler plugins on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, sticky

I'm using Zurb Foundation 6.3.1 on this site: https://www.brill.blog

On the home page, I'm using Foundation's Toggler plugin to hide/show a 'Featured posts' panel at the top of the page.

Lower on the page, I'm also using Foundation's Sticky plugin to control the scroll position of the sidebar for desktop window sizes.

Independently both these plugins work well.

However, after the Toggler’s hide button has been activated, the Sticky sidebar's positioning is still based on the original pageload, before Toggler was run, so it gets positioned too low on the page, overlapping the footer.

I believe that I need to either: 1. add a ‘mutation observer’ to the Sticky plugin to watch for changes in window height, or 2. add code at the end of the Toggler plugin to re-init the Sticky plugin.

Unfortunately, I don't yet have any JS skills, so I'd be really grateful for any help that explicitly tells me where to add the code, and what code to add!

I'm using CodeKit to prepend each plugin's js into my app.js from: /foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.toggler.js etc.

Do I hack these original plugin files, or add some code to my app.js?

I note that there is an open issue that could affect this: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/8394 (Re-initialization of a sticky element after it is destroyed does not get height), and there a couple of workarounds in the comments that I could try (if I just had a clue where to put them!)

Many thanks for any help!